# If $\mu$ is a distribution on the complex plane with compact support, then their restriction to the entire functions is analytic functional?

Tags: complex-analysis, distribution-theory

I'm trying to understand what the phrase means
"If $\mu$ is a distribution on the complex plane with compact support, then their restriction to the entire functions is analytic functional".

From what I understand, a distribution $T$ is a continuous linear functional defined on the test function space $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I also know that the support of a distribution $T$ is defined as the complement of the largest open set of $\Omega$ in which $T$ vanishes

**Question 1**. What is a distribution on the complex plane? Is $T:\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{C})\to \mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{C}\approx \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Where did you find this statement? It would be good to see the surrounding context since the usual spaces of test functions used to define spaces of distributions contain only bounded functions. But by Liouville's theorem, bounded and entire functions are constant so the statement seems a little strange.